# How to reduce the size of every input field from default 56px to 50px through out the project for vuetify components

Tags: css, vue.js, height, vuetify.js

The vuetify's field have default 56px height , which I want to reduce to 50px through out the project., without giving height prop to every vuetify input component.How can I do that. I tried to update some class and gave a height to 50px , but that made 50px height for the vuetify components that were explicitly given a height prop with some pixels.